# Angularjs, dynamically change reference in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

is it possible to change the reference from a directive dynamically at runtime ?

i have an input field like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="header in chartdata.cols">
<input myOwnDirective items-array="current_settings.y_values" ng-value="header.id | num"     type="checkbox">
</div>
```

i use in this input field my own directive and the directive gets a reference to the "current_settings.y_values" value. this is only a simple array. and the code above creates only 5 checkboxes..

my directive looks like this:

```
app.directive("myOwnDirective", [function () {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
        ItemsArray: "=",
        value: "@"
    },
    link: function (scope, elem) {

               ....

}]);
```

now i have in my controller this value: $scope.status; this value can be for example $scope.status='A' or $scope.status='B';

and i want now dynamically change the value from my input field 
    (items-array="current_settings.y_values")
if the status is 'A' it should store my data to current_settings.y_values and if the status is 'B' it should store the values on an other place like "current_settings.x_values"

how can i do that ?

EDIT: ok the solution from Chandermani works but i wont now do the same with an input field with a radio button and ng-model.. and there the solution did not work or do i something wrong ?

the input field looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="header in chartdata.cols">
<input ng-model="xValues.xValues" type="radio" name="xValues" ng-value="header.id | num">
</div>
```

in my controller the xValues is defined with

```
$scope.xValues={xValues: null}; // xValues is only one number not an array
```

if i change to status 'A' i do this:

$scope.xValues.xValues = $scope.current_settings.x_value;

but this will not work,the value is not stored in $scope.current_settings.x_value , what do i wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new property on your scope to reference the correct array when status changes. Use that to bind to directive scope.

```
$scope.$watch('status',function(newValue) {
    if(newValue) {
      if(newValue=='A') {
           $scope.values=$scope.current_settings.y_values
      }
      else {
           $scope.values=$scope.current_settings.x_values
      }
    }
});
```

In the directive html you use

`<input myOwnDirective items-array="values" ng-value="header.id | num"     type="checkbox">`

Comment: Ok your solution works but i have another problem, i want do the same with a radio input field and ng-model but this will not work, i have updated my first post.